# How to stop to proceed without using if statement and return value?

Tags: swift

I wrote a function that displays an alert that informs user of maintenance.

`checkMaintenanceAndDisplayAlert(viewController: viewController)`

However, I don't want the user to proceed to next page if the feature is under maintenance. How do it achieve this by not using `if` statement or return a value from the function?

the complete code is

```
func onDidTap(viewController: UIViewController?) {
    checkMaintenanceAndDisplayAlert(viewController: viewController)

    nextPage(viewController: viewController)
}
```

How do I not execute `nextPage` without breaking the pattern of this function?

Comment: What is `checkMaintenanceAndDisplayAlert(viewController: viewController)` and why is `UIViewController` optional in `onDidTap`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a guard statement, I’m not quite sure if that’s the answer you were looking for though.